# Jest: Mock class method in a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

So just trying to understand how I mock a class function within a function itself. How do I mock the data returned from the exchange.someFunction() method so I can test the actual getPositions() function itself?

```
const library = require('library');
const exchange = new library.exchange_name();

async function getPositions() {

    let positions = [];

    const results = await exchange.someFunction();
    // Do some stuff
    return results;

}
```

I was trying to do the following but have no idea if I'm doing anything correct at all

```
const exchange = require('../../exchange');
jest.mock('library')

it('get balances', async () => {
    library.someFunction.mockResolvedValue({
        data: [{some data here}]
   )}
}
```

Error thrown:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValue' of undefined
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const library = require('./library');
const exchange = new library.exchange_name();

async function getPositions() {
  let positions = [];

  const results = await exchange.someFunction();
  return results;
}

module.exports = getPositions;
```

`library.js`:

```js
function exchange_name() {
  async function someFunction() {
    return 'real data';
  }

  return {
    someFunction,
  };
}

module.exports = { exchange_name };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const getPositions = require('./');
const mockLibrary = require('./library');

jest.mock('./library', () => {
  const mockExchange = { someFunction: jest.fn() };
  return { exchange_name: jest.fn(() => mockExchange) };
});

describe('61649788', () => {
  it('get balances', async () => {
    const mockExchange = new mockLibrary.exchange_name();
    mockExchange.someFunction.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: ['mocked data'] });
    const actual = await getPositions();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ data: ['mocked data'] });
    expect(mockExchange.someFunction).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61649788/index.test.js (8.775s)
  61649788
    ✓ get balances (7ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.099s
```